# MS-Access Query to sum entries per week per person?

Tags: ms-access

I am very new to Access. I am trying to learn on my own through videos but have been somewhat thrown in on the deep end.

I have a table full of reports of individually inspected boxes of items. Every entry has a date, inspector number, and number of items inspected. Am I able to create an MS-Access query that reports the number of boxes inspected by an individual inspector (by inspector number) for each week, I picture each column being the sum of number of boxes for each row (inspector).

As of right now I have gotten a query that gives number of boxes per inspector, per month across the span of all time. So column one, for example, is summarizing the number of boxes an inspector has done every January since the beginning of the report rather than an individual January (or what I really need, an individual week).
Is this something that can be done in Access or am I overextending its usage (or perhaps misusing it all together)?

Current SQL query:

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(report.[Box quantity]) AS [SumOfBox quantity]
SELECT Val(report.[Inspector Number]), Sum(report.[Box quantity]) AS [Total Of Box quantity]
FROM report
GROUP BY report.[Inspector Number]
PIVOT Format([Date Issued],"mmm") In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
```

Comment: Why do you deem necessary to use Val() on [Inspector Number]? Show example data and indicate data types. Strongly advise not to use space in naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Extract year and week parts from date value for row and column headers. Consider:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Box quantity]) AS [SumOfBox quantity]
SELECT Val([Inspector Number]) AS InsNum, Year([Date Issued]) AS Yr, Sum([Box quantity]) AS [Total Of Box quantity]
FROM report
GROUP BY [Inspector Number], Year([Date Issued])
PIVOT DatePart("ww", [Date Issued])
```

If you want to assure a column for every week is generated, can use IN():
`In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53)`